# Bash script - How to make option priority more important than others

Tags: bash

I have my problem in my script with priority.
For example when i invoke my script ./script -q -h it should return the h option which should have more important priority than others. My code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
function usage
{       

echo "Echoing login, name, surname of the invoker

where:
-h  help
-q  quit(don't proceed script)"
}
function invalid
{
echo "Invalid argument!
"
usage
}
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
   case $1 in
     -h | --help )           usage
                             exit
                             ;;
     -q | --quit )           exit
                             ;;
     * )                     invalid
                             exit 1
   esac
 shift
done

echo $USER
getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f5 | cut -d, -f1
```

Comment: Why do you need an option to quit, anyway? For most interactive tools, quitting when you're done isn't optional.

Comment: It is just a homework. I also need to do the same script in tcsh and don't have any idea how to do this. It seems that for example tcsh doesn't have functions.

Comment: @triplee A place for a -q option might be a management tool for some service, where q can be seen as shutdown the service. Or start the service, read input files and keep running polling for new input files unless you have given a -q option. Or `do_a_lot; read_options; do_more_when_not_quit`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `case` check, just set variables (e.g. `opt_h=1` or `opt_q=1`).

Then check the variables afterwards in whatever order you want:

```
if [ -n "$opt_h" ]; then
    usage
    exit
fi
if [ -n "$opt_q" ]; then
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is by setting a variable in the case) block.
i.e.

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -h | --help ) DOHELP=true
                      ;;
        -q | --quit ) DOQUIT=true
                      ;;
        * )           echo "Invalid arg"
                      exit 1
    esac
    shift
done

if [ -n "$DOHELP" ]; then
   usage
   exit 0
fi

if [ -n "$DOQUIT" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: I think the OP will want a `DOHELP=true` after `echo "Invalid arg"`.

Comment: Of course, but this question was about how to give options preference, not good script design.